# Class binding in HTML

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make my div use class template if and only if some value is equal to 0. If the value is greater than 0, I want to use another class. How do I go about it easily?

```
 <a (click)="onItemsHeaderPanelClick()"
       [class.proj-style-display-flex.linked-items-label]="linkedItems.length > 0"
       [class.proj-style-display-flex.linked-items-label-disabled]="linkedItems.length == 0">
... </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngClass Using Evaluated Expression :

```
<a (click)="onItemsHeaderPanelClick()"
    [ngClass]="{
    'classA': mySuperExpressionOrVariable > 0,
    'classB': mySuperExpressionOrVariable === 0
    }">...</a>
```

Code explained :

- classA for mySuperExpressionOrVariable > 0
- classB for mySuperExpressionOrVariable === 0
- and no class for mySuperExpressionOrVariable < 0

There is many ways to user ngClass :

- ngClass Using String Syntax
- ngClass Using Array Syntax
- ngClass Using Evaluated Expression
- ngClass Using the Ternary Operator
- ngClass Usage Options

Answer (score 5):

```
<span [ngClass]="[linkedItems.length ? 'case-yes-class' : 'case-no-class']">content</span>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: that should be curly `{` instead of `[` in the conditions.

Comment: Okay, I never new it. thanx

Comment: No problem. I just copied a cope from my project and pasted here.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ngClass` directive

```
<span class="proj-style-display-flex" [ngClass]="{linkedItems.length === 0 ? 'linked-items-label-disabled' : 'linked-items-label'}">content</span>
```